# Build custom target by default in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'd like to run a custom command with cmake. That sounds like an incredibly simple task/question, but it's frustrating how difficult it is to find an example.

Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
$ cmake .
$ make
> Hello World! (Output)
```

In Gnu Make that's very easy:

```
bar: 
        echo Hello World!
```

But I'm trying to do this in cmake. Based on what I've been reading, I should be able to do that with the `CMakeLists.txt` file below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(foo)
add_custom_target(bar)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET   bar
  COMMAND  "echo Hello World!"
)
```

Currently there is no work to do if I just call `make`.  I need to explicitly call `make bar`. How can I add `bar` to the `all` recipe?

I've tried adding `add_dependency(foo bar)`, but `foo` is a non-existent target.  If there is some super-target that I'm unaware of that would be perfect.  Then I could just use that as the TARGET for my custom command and not bother with `bar`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `ALL` option for build the target *by default*:

```
add_custom_target(bar ALL)
```

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

When the custom command produces actually some stuff, instead of only print "Hello World", then the following might be appropriate.

```
add_custom_target(Work ALL DEPENDS that.txt)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT   that.txt
    COMMAND  generator --from this.txt --produce that.txt
    DEPENDS  this.txt
)
```

Comment: This works great. Also you do not need the `ALL` if another target depends on that custom target (i.e. `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} Work)`).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Tsyvarev's perfect answer, to simplify the cmakelists.txt file further we can do this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(foo)
add_custom_target(bar ALL
  COMMAND  "echo Hello World!"
)
```

This integrates the custom_command into the custom_target.