# CMake Custom Target Not Running

Tags: cmake

So I want to run a set of commands every time I do a build/make step. I have the CMakeLists.txt below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MyFiles)

set(
    DESTINATION_DIR
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/final"
)

set(
    FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files/file1.txt"
)

######################################################################
add_custom_target(
    FakeTarget
    DEPENDS FakeOutput    
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT FakeOutput

    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
    make_directory ${DESTINATION_DIR}

    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
    copy ${FILES} ${DESTINATION_DIR}
)
```

When I run cmake, a Makefile generates just fine, but running the Makefile does nothing. I know I'm probably missing something small, but think this looks right according to the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build custom target by default in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885692/build-custom-target-by-default-in-cmake)

Comment: Sure enough. I did a search, but didn't find that one. Sorry about that. That solution works.