# How to change the default target in Makefile generated by CMake

Tags: cmake, makefile, doxygen

**I want to produce a makefile through CMake not to set default_target as all.**

Through Unix Makefiles generator option, CMake generates Makefile like this

```
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target
```

In my case, I want to produce a document generated by doxygen when I call `make all`, excepting `make`.

```
cmake ..
make             // build without doxygen
make all         // build with doxygen
```

I want to build files to exclude Doxygen when `make` in shell
But, I want to build all of files when `make all`.
Therefore, I am looking for information how to change the default target in Makefile generated by CMake.

Doxygen is declared in `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
    set(document_files ${.....}/document/html)
    add_custom_target(doxygen ALL 
        DEPENDS ${document_files})

    # Documentation command 
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${document_files}
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${document_files}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${.....}/../docs
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM )
```

Comment: I think it is not good practice to have "make" and "make all" do different things.

Comment: "change the default target in Makefile generated by CMake" - I don't know how to do that and I think this is impossible. I agree with the previous commenter, that having `make` and `make all` to do different things would greatly confuse users of your project. You are better to resort to other name for the target "build with doxygen". E.g. `make product`.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885935/1657886 (i.e. the answer from @Tsyvarev on another question)? and try from there?

Comment: This is not possible in CMake, period.

Comment: The best approach could be to simply remove the `ALL` allowing you to use `cmake --build .` and `cmake --build . --target all doxygen` to build with or without doxygen respectively... You probably should swap the order of the cmake commnads though.

Comment: Thank you all of your service! I think that I need to consider all of your advice!